# Scheduled Trigger Flow - Only Works in Debug Mode

Tags: visual-workflow, time-dependent-workflow, scheduled-job

I am running into an issue with a flow that I created. For some reason when I run the flow in debug mode, it works perfectly and updates the records. If I schedule it to run... it does nothing.

Here is the flow. I have included the configuration of every object except the Action one. I know that that specific object is correct. Its an HTTP get to an API site to get an updated value.

[image: Current Flow]

If I run a debug log on it, I get the following:

```
59.0 APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;NBA,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
15:05:01.1 (1737918)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|xxx|xxx|(GMT-05:00) Eastern Standard Time (America/New_York)|GMT-05:00
15:05:01.1 (1876366)|EXECUTION_STARTED
15:05:01.1 (1889796)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|301E100000C5vCf|Currency_API_Update-47, ProcessType: AutoLaunchedFlow, Trigger: Scheduled
15:05:01.1 (146436156)|SCHEDULED_FLOW_DETAIL|Number of records retrieved in this schedule: 4
15:05:01.1 (146594344)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Currency_API_Update-47, ProcessType: AutoLaunchedFlow, Trigger: Scheduled
15:05:01.1 (146607665)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

And since there are 4 records retrieved, I get 4 debug logs back that all look identical to this but it doesn't seem like they do anything...:

```
59.0 APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;NBA,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
15:05:13.0 (216521)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|xxx|xxx|(GMT-05:00) Eastern Standard Time (America/New_York)|GMT-05:00
15:05:13.0 (276515)|EXECUTION_STARTED
15:05:13.0 (286854)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|limit check|Currency_API_Update
15:05:13.0 (414741)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Currency_API_Update
15:05:13.0 (422902)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

I am really struggling here as I have tried numerous different styles of implementing this flow. I tried a loop, without a loop, filtering the objects and using the $Record global variable... Nothing seems to work for me outside of debug mode.

Since the flow does contain an HTTP get api call, I made sure that my profile has proper access to the user credential object and I have full CRED.

[image: Profile Permissions]

Any help, comments, or questions would be greatly GREATLY appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT: 11/30/23 as per the request from @cropredy, I have added a large image that shows how I have my "GetCurrencies" action configured in addition to the "External Credentials" feature. I hope this additional information is helpful in determining why this flow appears to do nothing.

[image: API Configuration]

Comment: Scheduled Flows run as Automated Process User if at V53 or the Process Automation user is not set.  when running "live" - who is the true running user and does that user have access to the Named Credential/External Credential configured for the HTTP call?

Comment: @cropredy the user that is set for the process automation is myself and I have the profile of system administrator which I believe should suffice for access to the named credential. 

I'm not sure if there anything I need to do in addition to this: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.named_credentials_permsets_profiles.htm&type=5

Comment: the link was about legacy named credentials and your post implies you are using External Credentials; please clarify and if the latter,  use [edit] to show how configured

Comment: @cropredy I have updated the post to clarify the legacy named credentials/external credentials thing. It is confusing because the verbiage has merged into one. This is a named credential but it is legacy type.

Comment: when you look at the debug log for the "live" schedule-triggered flow, can you confirm the running user is you?

Comment: @cropredy Yes, I redacted some information in the main post , but it specifies my name in the USER_INFO field. It shows my USER ID followed by my email used for the specific sandbox.

USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|0055w00000CFdKI|cdutko@xxxxxx.devbox2

Comment: I'm temporarily out of ideas; I'd double check the [Trailhead on Flows and External Credentials](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/use-external-services-with-a-flow).